# Вытащить данные c помощью regEx

Tags: регулярные-выражения

С помощью regEx из файла вытащить `1,2,3` то что в скобках?

```
1,Vasya,Petrov,PHP Developer,{1,2,3},50000.0
```

[0-9][\,][0-9][^}] выделяет только 1,2

Comment: Должно быть достаточно [`{([0-9,]+)}`](https://regex101.com/r/y8o2lv/1). Нужное значение в группе №1.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, тогда уж: `/{(.+?)}/g`, не сказано же "числа и запятые в скопках".

Comment: @MedvedevDev `[0-9][\,][0-9][^}]` свидетельствует об обратном.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, резонно, с другой стороны когда человек не знает как делать, он и делает не как надо, а как пришло в голову. Это все равно что человек хочет сварить кашу рисовую, но делает из топора, а ты его учишь его делать не рисовую, а из топора, но вкусную... xDDD